# How RabbitMQ batch publishing (using CreateBasicPublishBatch) can affect ordering?

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq

I'm using rabbitmq-dotnet-client to publish batches of messages using `IModel.CreateBasicPublishBatch()`.

My requirement is to guarantee the delivery of all records in a table, 1 record = 1 message, and preserve the order in which they were stored in the database.

```cs
        var batch = channel.CreateBasicPublishBatch();
        foreach (var row in repository.ReadOrderedRecords())
        {
            var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            properties.Persistent = true;
            var message = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(row, jsonOptions));
            batch.Add("", "my-queue", true, properties, message);
        }
        channel.ConfirmSelect();
        batch.Publish();
        channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie(publishTimeout);
```

I'm using confirmation, but the question is: does it make this operation atomic? I mean, I think to ensure order and delivery of all messages, batch publishing would need to be atomic. Otherwise, if one message fails and others are published, I will lose that message or lose ordering if I retry that message alone. If it's atomic, I can retry the entire batch, preserving the order.

Is `BasicPublishBatch` with confirmation atomic? How does it handle partial failures? Does it make partial delivery?